# I am trying to write the following 2 matrices in latex

Tags: math-mode, equations, matrices

These are images of the equations, I tried the bmatrix environment and it didn't work with me, I am also trying to make it as an equation so the numbering works

[image]

Comment: The `bmatrix` environment is the way to go, so it's not clear how it could not have worked. Please post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
[\text{\bf M}]_\text{consistent}=\tfrac{SL}{420}
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[light-syntax]
  156 22L 54 -13L;
  22L 4L^2 13L -3L^2;
  54 13L 156 -22L;
  -13L -3L^2 -22L 4L^2
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```